# Don't know how to build task 'db:create'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm migrating from a sqllite db to mysql2.  I have mysql running (and changed database.yml) but for some reason my rake db:create comes back with:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:create'
```

When I do a:  rake -T, no db tasks appear in the list.

I'm on Rails 3.2.9

What obvious thing am I missing here?

Comment: are you running it from the right directory?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just figured it out.  Someone had commented out the following in application.rb:

```
require 'rails/all'
```

Once put back rake -T returns the db tasks.

Answer (score 5):

For people landing here in 2019:

If you ran `rails new` with `-O` (Capital 'O') or `--skip-activerecord` and want to add a database later, you need to uncomment this in `application.rb` to enable the Active Record framework:

`require "active_record/railtie"`

*Edit:*
You will also need to create the following structure in your application's root dir:

```
your_app
  |_config
    |_ database.yml
  |_db
    |_ migrate
    |_ schema.rb
```

then run:
`rake db:schema:dump`